# Cannot convert Persian DateTime to Gregorian

Tags: c#

i'm confused! I am using this code to convert a list of Persian datetimes to Gregorian but they don't seem to be converted:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var lst = new List<string> { "1392/08/05", "1393/09/10", "1391/05/09" };
    var persian = new PersianCalendar();
    foreach (var persianDateTime in lst)
    {
        var d = persianDateTime.Split('/');
        var gregorianDate = persian.ToDateTime(int.Parse(d[0]), int.Parse(d[1]), int.Parse(d[2]), 0, 0, 0, 0);
        Console.WriteLine(gregorianDate.ToShortDateString());
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
 }
```

Result is :

[image]

Comment: Thank your for the complete code example. But please explain precisely what output you expected and why. What is the current culture settings of your PC? Is it possible you are already set to a Persian culture or are otherwise using a globalization setting that would cause `DateTime` to default to Persian dates?

Comment: I'm getting different output : 2013-10-27
2014-12-01
2012-07-30

Comment: I'm using Windows 10  and VS 2015 .

Comment: why can't convert to Gregorian DateTime ?

Comment: I'm already set to a Persian culture .

Comment: Please read [MCVE] guidance and update your post accordingly. Also it does not look like your problem is in any way related to `foreach`, or splitting strings... Please remove all unrelated code and replace values with constants where possible. Make sure to provide expected values too.

Comment: Are you sure that the result is wrong. I did some test with online converter and the result match

Comment: When you call `ToShortDateString()` this is a culture based method, so if your current culture is Persian, it is probably converting the `DateTime` back to Persian for you.

Comment: _"I'm already set to a Persian culture"_ -- then why do you expect `DateTime` to display the date using the Gregorian calendar? You need to format the text using the `GregorianCalendar` method, or pass a culture that uses the Gregorian calendar when formatting the `DateTime` object. Your question isn't clear at all...the computer's doing exactly what you asked it to. What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correctly converting the date, but then you are calling `ToShortDateString()` which is using your current culture to display the value. As [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) says:

> The string returned by the ToShortDateString method is culture-sensitive.

You are using the Persian culture, so the output string is returned in Persian format.

Edit: to see the actual value, you can of course use the [overload of `DateTime.ToString()` which accepts an `IFormatProvider` parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht77y576(v=vs.110).aspx) and pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, or whichever culture you wish to use to format the value:

```
gregorianDate.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: when i use without  ToShortDateString method , result is :

05/08/1392 12:00:00 ?.?
10/09/1393 12:00:00 ?.?
09/05/1391 12:00:00 ?.?

Comment: Are those _the actual values contained in the objects_ or are you calling (say) `ToString()` instead?

Comment: Thanks .
Console.WriteLine(gregorianDate.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));